# What is the value of this php variable

Tags: php, testing

I'm learning php now and the command array() is confusing me.

```
$opts = array(
    'apple'=>array(
    'banana'=>"GET",
    'orange'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
  );
```

I tried to echo opts, but the output was simply the word "ARRAY". I wonder what happened and how was $opts supposed to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use var_dump($array); or print_r($array) instead of echo

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: When a question asked in 2023 can be resolved by offering a single native function call, you can be very sure that the question is a duplicate.  Please help Stack Overflow to eliminate its content redundancy problem by not answering duplicate questions.  If you have something unique and valuable to say on the topic, please post your insights on the dupe target.  If you don't have anything new to add to Stack Overflow, please do not answer.